# How to set superscript for expandable parentheses?

Tags: superscripts, chemfig, parenthesis

The following code compiled with error:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{R-C(=[:60]O)-[:-60]O-H}
    \arrow{<=>}
    \chemleft[\chemfig{R-C(=[:60]O)-[:-60]O}\chemright]^{-}
    \+
    \chemfig{H^+}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

I'd like to place that minus sign on the upper right corner of the right parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the corresponding formula inside a `\subscheme` it will get a node name that you can refer to from another tikzpicture with `remember picture,overlay` for which `chemfig` has the shortcut `\chemmove`. Then you can add anything anywhere:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

% \schemedebug{true} % look up and visualize the nodes and node names

\schemestart
  \chemfig{R-C(=[:60]O)-[:-60]O-H}
  \arrow{<=>}
  \subscheme{\chemleft[\chemfig{R-C(=[:60]O)-[:-60]O}\chemright]}
  \+
  \chemfig{H^+}
\schemestop
\chemmove[red]{
  \node[right] at (c3.north east) {top right} ;
  \node[right] at (c3.south east) {bottom right} ;
  \node[left] at (c3.north west) {top left} ;
  \node[left] at (c3.south west) {bottom left} ;
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{R-C(=[:60]O)-[:-60]O-H}
\arrow{<=>}
\chemleft[\chemfig{R-C(=[:60]O)-[:-60]O}\chemright{]^{-}}
\+
\chemfig{H^+}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

> ChemFig provides the `\chemleft` and `\chemright` command pair. These allow to set expandable delimiters on either side of a material. The commands must be followed by delimiters, just like in the case of TeX primitive commands `\left` and `\right`:
>
> ```
> \chemleft<car1><material>\chemright<car2>
> ```
>
> where `<car1>` and `<car2>` can be “(” et “)” or “[” and “]”, or any other expandable delimiter consistent with the
> `\left` et `\right` commands.

I just tried: miracles happen. `;-)`

Comment: Thanx! Never thought of it - maybe too trivial.

Comment: @ThomasBenko The documentation uses `<car2>` suggesting differently, so it was not at all a trivial question.